# Determining whether two scrambled strings are equivalent

Tags: java, strings, array

I was able to complete the problem doing it in this manner, but I would assume there has to be an easier way.

Sample input:

> abc, cba

Output:

> Both strings of characters are equivalent.

Or

> abc, acc

Output:

> Different

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1, str2;
        int aCount = 0, bCount = 0, cCount = 0, dCount = 0, eCount = 0, fCount = 0, gCount = 0, hCount = 0, iCount = 0, jCount = 0, kCount = 0, lCount = 0, mCount = 0, nCount = 0, oCount = 0, pCount = 0, qCount = 0, rCount = 0, sCount = 0, tCount = 0, uCount = 0, vCount = 0, wCount = 0, xCount = 0, yCount = 0, zCount = 0;
        int aCount2 = 0, bCount2 = 0, cCount2 = 0, dCount2 = 0, eCount2 = 0, fCount2 = 0, gCount2 = 0, hCount2 = 0, iCount2 = 0, jCount2 = 0, kCount2 = 0, lCount2 = 0, mCount2 = 0, nCount2 = 0, oCount2 = 0, pCount2 = 0, qCount2 = 0, rCount2 = 0, sCount2 = 0, tCount2 = 0, uCount2 = 0, vCount2 = 0, wCount2 = 0, xCount2 = 0, yCount2 = 0, zCount2 = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out
                .println("Enter your first string that you want compared (lowercase only):");

        str1 = input.next();
        str1 = str1.trim();
        char[] charArr1 = str1.toCharArray();

        System.out
                .println("Enter your second string that you want compared (lowercase only):");

        str2 = input.next();
        str2 = str2.trim();
        char[] charArr2 = str2.toCharArray();

        input.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < charArr1.length; i++) {
            if (charArr1[i] == 'a')
                aCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'b')
                bCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'c')
                cCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'd')
                dCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'e')
                eCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'f')
                fCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'g')
                gCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'h')
                hCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'i')
                iCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'j')
                jCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'k')
                kCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'l')
                lCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'm')
                mCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'n')
                nCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'o')
                oCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'p')
                pCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'q')
                qCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'r')
                rCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 's')
                sCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 't')
                tCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'u')
                uCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'v')
                vCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'w')
                wCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'x')
                xCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'y')
                yCount++;
            if (charArr1[i] == 'z')
                zCount++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < charArr2.length; i++) {
            if (charArr2[i] == 'a')
                aCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'b')
                bCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'c')
                cCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'd')
                dCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'e')
                eCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'f')
                fCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'g')
                gCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'h')
                hCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'i')
                iCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'j')
                jCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'k')
                kCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'l')
                lCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'm')
                mCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'n')
                nCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'o')
                oCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'p')
                pCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'q')
                qCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'r')
                rCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 's')
                sCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 't')
                tCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'u')
                uCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'v')
                vCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'w')
                wCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'x')
                xCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'y')
                yCount2++;
            if (charArr2[i] == 'z')
                zCount2++;
        }
        if (aCount == aCount2 && bCount == bCount2 && cCount == cCount2
                && dCount == dCount2 && eCount == eCount2 && fCount == fCount2
                && gCount == gCount2 && hCount == hCount2 && iCount == iCount2
                && jCount == jCount2 && kCount == kCount2 && lCount == lCount2
                && mCount == mCount2 && nCount == nCount2 && oCount == oCount2
                && pCount == pCount2 && qCount == qCount2 && rCount == rCount2
                && sCount == sCount2 && tCount == tCount2 && uCount == uCount2
                && vCount == vCount2 && wCount == wCount2 && xCount == xCount2
                && yCount == yCount2 && zCount == zCount2)
            System.out.println("Both strings of characters are equivilent.");
        else
            System.out.println("Different");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick hint: Whenever you got lines of code that are repeated all over with minor variations such as variable names in your case, use an (additional) array and loop other that instead

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is where the [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) utility class comes in handy. You can use it to sort the character arrays underlying both strings and then compare the sorted character arrays:

```
public static boolean equivalent(String s1, String s2) {
    char[] chars1 = s1.toCharArray();
    char[] chars2 = s2.toCharArray();

    Arrays.sort(chars1);
    Arrays.sort(chars2);

    return Arrays.equals(chars1, chars2);
}
```

This method yields the expected results:

```
assert equivalent("abc", "cba");
assert !equivalent("abc", "acc");
```

If there's a possibility for one or both of the input strings to be null, you could add the following two checks to the beginning of the method:

```
if (s1 == null && s2 == null) return true;
if (s1 == null || s2 == null) return false;
```

If performance is important, you could also add a string length comparison to avoid unnecessary array sorting:

```
if (s1.length() != s2.length()) return false;
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this. Is this sorting by unicode I assume.

Comment: By numerical value of the `char` primitives. It doesn't really matter though, as long as they're both sorted the same way.

Comment: Great answer. Small suggestion: An edge case where one or both parameters are null isn't covered. If both are null I'd return true and if only one is null, false.

Comment: @Anrej Good suggestion. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Only works for simple characters. Doesn't handle UTF-16 surrogate pairs, combining marks are other kinds of unicode equivalences.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Agreed. I assumed this not to be an issue since the code under review only covered lowercase ASCII.

Comment: You could optimize by taking string length into consideration.

Comment: @Matthew Thanks for the feedback. I didn't do it in my original version because I would be wildly surprised if `Array.equals()` doesn't perform a length comparison first. However, that still leaves the potentially unnecessary sorting of both arrays, so I updated my answer.

Comment: if performance is important it's likely to be faster with a hashing than a comparison of all the elements. Yes that will yield a probabilistic result but the likely hood of it being wrong is easily lower than the likely hood of the computer being destroyed by lightning

Comment: @RuneFS I suggest that you come up with an implementation to back up your claims. As it stands, your comment is neither here nor there.

Comment: Fair enough :) it's in my answer

Answer (score 7):

Consider using this approach.

```
static boolean same(String s1, String s2)
{
    if (s1 == null && s2 == null) return true;
    if (s1 == null || s2 == null) return false;
    if (s1.length() != s2.length()) return false;

    Map<Character, Integer> m = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    long diff = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        Character c1 = s1.charAt(i);
        Character c2 = s2.charAt(i);
        diff += c1 - c2;
        if (!m.containsKey(c1)) m.put(c1, 0);
        m.put(c1, m.get(c1) + 1);
        if (!m.containsKey(c2)) m.put(c2, 0);
        m.put(c2, m.get(c2) - 1);
    }
    if (diff != 0) return false;             // string checksum is different

    Iterator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> it = m.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
        if (it.next().getValue() != 0)
            return false;                    // char count is different     
    return true;
}
```

Tested with

```
@Test
public void stringCompare()
{
    assertTrue(HelloWorld.same(null, null));
    assertFalse(HelloWorld.same("abc", null));
    assertFalse(HelloWorld.same(null, "cba"));
    assertFalse(HelloWorld.same("ac", "cba"));

    assertTrue(HelloWorld.same("abc", "cba"));
    assertTrue(HelloWorld.same(
            "Hey this is the same thing!", 
            "!this eyHthing is the sa me"));
    assertFalse(HelloWorld.same("abd", "bcb"));
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look right. `assertTrue(HelloWorld.same("abd", "bcb"));` will succeed while it should not.

Comment: Correct. The check sum approach fails in this case.

Comment: Added a map to account for same length strings with same checksum. Thanks @Robby Cornelissen for the counter example that exposed the issue.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like O(n) to me... How'd you get O(n log n)?

Comment: Also you *can* use `foreach` instead of setting up your own iterator if you like.

Comment: @LukeWillis this is due to using the Map. Originally it was a for loop only with O(N).

Comment: @Andrej `HashMap`s are constant-time (amortized) for puts and gets. It looks to me like this is still O(N) even in the worst case where the two strings are large, and only differ by one character. This is because the first loop would run in O(N) time, and the second loop would run in up to O(N) time, which is simply O(N) total.

Comment: Good point on hashmap amortized constant time @skeggse

Answer (score 4):

Try utilizing dictionaries like so. (This is untested).

```
Map<Character, Integer> letterMap1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
Map<Character, Integer> letterMap2 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < charArr1.length; i++) {
    if (!letterMap1.containsKey(charArr1[i])) {
        letterMap1.put(charArr1[i], 0);
    }  else {
        letterMap1.put(charArr1[i], letterMap1.get(charArr1[i]) + 1);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < charArr2.length; i++) {
    if (!letterMap2.containsKey(charArr2[i])) {
        letterMap2.put(charArr2[i], 0);
    }  else {
        letterMap2.put(charArr2[i], letterMap2.get(charArr2[i]) + 1);
    }
}

boolean equivalent = true;

if (letterMap1.size() == letterMap2.size()) {
    for (Character c : letterMap1.keySet()) {
        if (!letterMap2.containsKey(c)) {
            equivalent = false;
            break;
        } else {
            if (letterMap1.get(c) != letterMap2.get(c)) {
                equivalent = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    equivalent = false;
}

if (equivalent) {
    System.out.println("Yes");
} else {
    System.out.println("No");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a probabilistic algorithm, one that's usually correct but might once in a while fail.

```
private static boolean eq(String l1, String l2){
    //if the length are different the result must be false
    if(l1.length() != l2.length()) {return false;}

    char[] c1 = l1.toCharArray();
    char[] c2 = l2.toCharArray();
    long sum1 = 1;
    long sum2 = 1;

    //iterate over the arrays of characters
    for(int i = 0; i<c1.length; i++){
        //from an array of primes take the one corresponding to the character
        int f1 = primes[c1[i]];
        int f2 = primes[c2[i]];

        //multiply the intermediate hash with the prime
        sum1 = sum1 * f1;
        sum2 = sum2 * f2;
    }
    //if the sums match the string are (likely) equivalent
    return sum1 == sum2;
}
```

I test ran this against [Robby's implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/70364/18661) as he suggested. I ran 1,000,000 iterations with strings of 160 characters
the execution times for the implementation based on `Arrays.equals` was between 7s and 10s
The execution times for the algorithm in this answer was between 0.5s and 0.6s

They would probably also scale differently since one is based on sort and the other is not. With the tests I've run there's however no really clear evidence of that but I did not run with large strings which would typically be required to see any real differences in scaling.

This algorithm can theoretically produce the wrong result. This would happen if one of the sums overflow and resulted in a new value of 0 the likelihood of which should be `1:64^2` for random input. In the case of one of the sums being zero one could fall back on the `Arrays.equals` implementation. It is possible that there might be other erroneous situations than the one with an overflow to zero, I haven't tried to prove that only tested a few assumptions empirically

Comment: The first 256 primes

Answer (score 3):

Because your code is a bit amateurish, I'm going to use a different approach to showing a solution, basically, how to arrive at it.

We can think of the two strings as sets of characters.  How would a human solve this problem? They would pick the first letter of a string, and see if that letter exists in the second string.  If so, they would then cross that letter off.  Repeat until you have no letters in the first string remaining.

If you never find a letter in that second string, then you know they can't be equivalent.  There are also short cuts you can take by checking for string length and null values.

That basic human approach is shown below.  You will quickly realize there are ways to optimize this, such as by sorting the strings in alphabetical order.  That means that you don't have to check as many letters before hitting a match.  With library functions, you can distill all these optimizations into the short example shown by *Robby Cornelissen*.

There are more esoteric solutions possible involving dictionaries and hashing, or one-liners using streams and integer summing, but I like keeping things easy to follow.

Here is the naive solution that leads to that:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestEquivalence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(AreStringsEquivalent("a", "b"));
        System.out.println(AreStringsEquivalent("a", "a"));
        System.out.println(AreStringsEquivalent("aaa", "bbb"));
        System.out.println(AreStringsEquivalent("abc", "abc"));
        System.out.println(AreStringsEquivalent("cba", "abc"));
        System.out.println(AreStringsEquivalent("cba", ""));
        System.out.println(AreStringsEquivalent("", ""));
        System.out.println(AreStringsEquivalent(null, "abc"));
        System.out.println(AreStringsEquivalent(null, ""));
    }

    public static boolean AreStringsEquivalent(String a, String b)
    {
        if (a == null && b == null) return true;

        if (a == null || b == null) return false;

        if (a.length() != b.length()) return false;

        char[] aArray = a.toCharArray();

        List<Character> bList = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for(char c : b.toCharArray()){
            bList.add(c);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < aArray.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bList.size(); j++)
            {
                if (aArray[i] == bList.get(j))
                {
                    bList.remove(j);
                    break;
                }

                if (j == bList.size() - 1)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your final implementation is O(N^2), and thus isn't optimized given that your so-called naive approach is also O(N^2). This might actually be O(N^3) because removing an element from the middle of an array list is O(N), because it has to copy every element in front of the removed element back one.

Answer (score 2):

Runs in O(N).

Sorry, this is C#, but the same idea should work in Java.

```
    public bool SameCharacters(string string1, string string2)
    {
        var encoding = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;

        Byte[] bytes1 = encoding.GetBytes(string1);
        Byte[] bytes2 = encoding.GetBytes(string2);

        if (string1.Length != string2.Length) return false;

        int[] counts = new int[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < string1.Length; i++)
        {
            counts[bytes1[i]]++;
            counts[bytes2[i]]--;
        }

        foreach (var count in counts)
        {
            if (count != 0) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

This just takes advantage of the fact that each character has a numeric value.  If you wanted to consider more than just ascii, you could replace the count array with a map from int -> int and use a different encoding.

Comment: YOu could just do `return counts.sum()==0` which might be a little more effiecent

Comment: It wouldn't work to check the sum.  string1 could have an 'a' and not an 'm' and string2 could have an 'm' and not an 'a' and the sum would still be zero.

Comment: I see now, sorry, you could instead sum the absolute value of the array

Comment: It wouldn't work since one value in the count could be 1 and the another would be -1.  The sum would be zero, but there would be non-zero values in the counts array.

Comment: something like `counts.Select(x => Math.Abs(x)).sum()`

Comment: Yes, that would work.  And, while it is elegant in notation, the System.Linq implementation of Sum and Select would still iterate over the whole array, call the Math.Abs method for each item and add it to another value.  It would be quite a bit more expensive than running a comparison to each value.  To do it in one line using Linq you could do: `return !counts.Any(x => x != 0);`

Comment: instead of negating the result of any you could simply do 
`return counts.All(x => x == 0)` which I personally think expresses the intention better.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to canonicalize both strings by sorting them and checking that the canonical strings are equal. This approach takes O(n lg n) using a comparison-based sort. A linear time algorithm for this problem exists: keep an array of counts of each letter for both strings. If the two array agree output is YES, it's NO elsewise.